# Symfony routing annotation Entity

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations

I need to get 2 entity objects from the path parameter in Symfony 3.
From the [document](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression), I can do:

```
/**
* @Route("/blog/{id}/comments/{comment_id}")
* @Entity("comment", expr="repository.find(comment_id)")
*/
public function showAction(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
}
```

However, I could not find out where that `@Entity` comes from. The page return with error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Entity" in method ABCBundle\Controller\ABCController::editAction() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in /srv/www/symfony3/src/ABCBundleController (which is being imported from "/srv/www/symfony3/src/ABCBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml").
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add this `use` statement:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;
```

See [SensioFrameWorkExtraBundle at github](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Configuration/Entity.php)